# Does every circuit's pin marked with MSB and LSB? Is it necessary?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I would like to know whether it is necessary to mark the pins of a circuit as LSB and MSB. For an Arithmetic circuit, I think it is necessary but is it necessary for any type of circuit?

Comment: There are plenty of circuits where such markings would simply not make any sense; where would you put them in a purely analog circuit, for instance? There's no bits in sight!

Answer (score 1):

Also look at a typical SRAM chip. Since every memory cell is exactly the same, you could easily mix up bits on the data lane, and separately mix up bits on the address lane, and all your memory would be still accessible by the mcu in a linear address space and with a correct order of bits (until you don't use bit lines which are outside of your data or address space on the mcu)

Comment: While this is true for chips that are being used only in-circuit, like RAM chips, there will be an issue with chips that are also used outside the circuit.. For example, for flash memory which is being programmed before board assembly, you need tomatch the pin numbering of the programming device.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary for every kind of circuit. For many circuits there is no difference between the functions of different similar pins. Consider, for example, an octal tristate driver.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circuit and your goals.

If you were using an sram, it would not matter that much as it does not generate values; it only returns whatever the cpu stored in it.

If we were talking about rom devices (eprom, eeprom, flash, etc.) it matters as the cpu must access it at fixed addresses and recover the data patterns in a certain format - it places "new" contents in the data bus if asked.

If considering microprocessors, video devices or other peripheral ic their pins must be matched for correct operation.

Logic gates do not require their pins to be arranged in order, just respect inputs and outputs but when having codifiers, decodifiers, multiplexers, demultiplexers, counters or arithmetic components order shall be respected.